# Leave-one-out-cross-validation query

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I am currently trying to understand a topic in Artificial Intelligence (Learning) and need assistance in understanding the following:

Why would a Leave-one-out-cross-validation algorithm, when used in conjunction with a majority classifier, score zero instead of 50% on a data set of equal number of positive and negative examples?

Thank you for your guidance on this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, when you leave out the positive sample, the training set has more negative samples; therefore the left out sample is classified as negative. And vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Don, so is it a case of like once a positive sample is left out, it gets classified as negative (hence now 101 negative 99 positive), and then when another positive gets left out, it is classified negative too (now 102 negative, 98 positive), and so on until everything is classified as negative, hence zero is always returned?

Comment: In leave-one-out cross-validation, you train your classifier on all of your data, except one randomly selected sample, then test it on that sample. And you repeat this several times. When you have an equal number of positive and negative samples, no matter which kind of sample you take out, it will be classified as the other kind, because the other kind will make up more than half of the testing samples.